# Can I travel on a UK visit visa's start date?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, legal

I have applied for a standard UK visit visa (6 months). I got the visa with a validity starting on 14 August 2018 (FROM DU date 14/08/18).

So can I travel from India on that date if I have a flight for the UK on 14/08/18 at 02:30 am?

My nationality is Indian. My journey starts from my country.

Comment: What date did you tell UKVI that you would arrive?

Comment: In application form UKVI I have mentioned arrival date 15 Aug 2018

Comment: What time are you due to arrive in the UK on that flight?

Comment: 14/08/18 at 02:30 pm

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid? I do not understand how you could think the visa would not be valid on its listed validity date?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I also believe that it should be valid as I am leaving on a listed valid date. But before buy ticket, I just want to make sure. Thanks

Comment: Nobody has ripped a hole in spacetime to cause the same day to suddenly be a different day.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, as long as your visa will be valid on your scheduled time of arrival in the UK you are fine. Why would you not be able to travel on the same date as the first date of your visa validity? Its fine.

You can't tell the airline check-in staff hey I will reach there just 1 hour before my visa validity please let me board: that's a no no in most cases. But in your case you are scheduled to reach 2.5 hours into your visa's validity; Forsee no problems with boarding.